# C# Get derived class as local var according to given type and use it out of scope

Tags: c#

I can not figure out how to prevent code dublication for that code block.

There is a base class That is Base_Reader and derived types like JT_Reader, IGES_Reader etc.

But base class dont have methods that childs have. Also I can not Change these because they come with dll.

Here are code sample;

```
string aModelExpansion = Path.GetExtension(filePath).ToLower();

if (aModelExpansion == "jt")
{
    var aReader = ModelReaderFactory.CreateReader<JT_Reader>(); 
//Remaining parts are exactly same, I just need to use aReader according to my extension.
    var aReaderParamaters = aReader.Parameters(); 
    
    aReaderParamaters.SetDelayedConversion(Settings.DelayedConversion);
    aReader.ReadFile(new Base_UTF16String(filePath));
    //convert STEP to MDM
    ModelData_Model aLoadedModel = new ModelData_Model();
    var s = aReader.Transfer(aLoadedModel);
    //convert MDM to GameObject
    Unity_ObjectFactory aConventer = new Unity_ObjectFactory();
    string aModelName = filePath.Split('/')[filePath.Split('/').Length - 1];
    _meshParentGameObject = aConventer.Create(aLoadedModel, aModelName);

    yield return new WaitUntil(() => _meshParentGameObject != null);
}

if (aModelExpansion == "iges")
{
    var aReader = ModelReaderFactory.CreateReader<IGES_Reader>();
    var aReaderParamaters = aReader.Parameters();
    
    aReaderParamaters.SetDelayedConversion(Settings.DelayedConversion);
    aReader.ReadFile(new Base_UTF16String(filePath));
    //convert STEP to MDM
    ModelData_Model aLoadedModel = new ModelData_Model();
    var s = aReader.Transfer(aLoadedModel);
    //convert MDM to GameObject
    Unity_ObjectFactory aConventer = new Unity_ObjectFactory();
    string aModelName = filePath.Split('/')[filePath.Split('/').Length - 1];
    _meshParentGameObject = aConventer.Create(aLoadedModel, aModelName);

    yield return new WaitUntil(() => _meshParentGameObject != null); 
}

// Generic type creator 
public static T CreateReader<T>() where T : Base_Reader, new()
{
    return new T();
}
  //Method signatures for readers
  // public JT_ReaderParameters Parameters() => new JT_ReaderParameters(CadExJTPINVOKE.JT_Reader_Parameters(this.swigCPtr), true);

   // public IGES_ReaderParameters Parameters() => new IGES_ReaderParameters(CadExIGESPINVOKE.IGES_Reader_Parameters(this.swigCPtr), true);
```

I dont want to create code blocks for all my model extensions.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: what is `ModelReaderFactory.CreateReader`? Is it your custom method? Also can you please add signatures for the readers methods? If they are the same - you can create some kind of wrapper/adapter so you are able to expose needed methods in them.

Comment: Sorry for the missed part. Yes, I created a generic method that returns given derived type. I will add it to code block.  Of course I can show the signatures but they dont look same.

Comment: It's hard to give a complete answer because you haven't detailed which methods _are_ part of the base class. But a general approach would be to abstract out the parts that are different into an interface and create separate Adapter classes that implement that interface for each of your known cases. Then make your common code just interact with that interface.

Comment: (If you want to play really fast-and-loose, you could try using `dynamic`, but I wouldn't recommend it without knowing more about your situation.)

Comment: Yes dynamic solve my problem, I get exact reader at runtime and can use its methods. Thanks a lot, I didn't even think that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would probably use the Template Pattern here.

Start out by creating a base class with the shared algorithm and some algorithm identifier, as well as a common interface. I would just use the name as the identifer, just like you have been doing.

```
public interface IExpander
{
    string Identifier { get; }
    IEnumerable<WaitUntil> Read(string filePath);
}

public abstract class BaseExpander<T> : IExpander where T : Base_Reader
{
    public abstract string Identifier { get; }
    public abstract T CreateReader();

    public IEnumerable<WaitUntil> Read(string filePath)
    {
        var reader = CreateReader();
        var aReaderParamaters = reader.Parameters();

        aReaderParamaters.SetDelayedConversion(Settings.DelayedConversion);
        reader.ReadFile(new Base_UTF16String(filePath));
        //convert STEP to MDM
        ModelData_Model aLoadedModel = new ModelData_Model();
        var s = reader.Transfer(aLoadedModel);
        //convert MDM to GameObject
        Unity_ObjectFactory aConventer = new Unity_ObjectFactory();
        string aModelName = filePath.Split('/')[filePath.Split('/').Length - 1];
        _meshParentGameObject = aConventer.Create(aLoadedModel, aModelName);

        yield return new WaitUntil(() => _meshParentGameObject != null);
    }


    /* not sure what these are only added them here to compile*/
    private object _meshParentGameObject;
    public IConfiguration Settings { get; private set; }
}
```

After that, I would then create the specialized expanders, one for each type. So, two like so:

```
public class JTExpander : BaseExpander<JT_Reader>
{
    public override string Identifier => "jt";
    public IModelReaderFactory ModelReaderFactory { get; }


    public JTExpander(IModelReaderFactory ModelReaderFactory)
    {
        this.ModelReaderFactory = ModelReaderFactory;
    }

    public override JT_Reader CreateReader()
        => ModelReaderFactory.CreateReader<JT_Reader>();
}

public class IGESExpander : BaseExpander<IGES_Reader>
{
    public override string Identifier => "iges";
    public IModelReaderFactory ModelReaderFactory { get; }


    public IGESExpander(IModelReaderFactory ModelReaderFactory)
    {
        this.ModelReaderFactory = ModelReaderFactory;
    }

    public override IGES_Reader CreateReader()
        => ModelReaderFactory.CreateReader<IGES_Reader>();
}
```

In order to use them, I would have to have something that knows about all expanders and can decide which one to use. So a factory seems like a nice fit. Small note, I would usually use dependency injection here and register all implementations of BaseExpander in the IoC container, and the create a dictionary out of them with the identifier as key. I'll leave that up to you as an exercise. My factory would look something like this:

```
public class ExpanderFactory
{
    private IEnumerable<IExpander> expanders;

    public ExpanderFactory()
    {
        IModelReaderFactory factory = new ModelReaderFactory();
        expanders = new List<IExpander>
        {
            new JTExpander(factory),
            new IGESExpander(factory)
        };
    }

    IExpander GetExpander(string expansionIdentifier)
        => expanders.First(x => x.Identifier == expansionIdentifier);
}
```

Finally, stitching it all together, it would look something like this:

```
public class SomeParentProcess
{
    ExpanderFactory factory = new ExpanderFactory();
           
    public void Expand(string path)
    {
        var extension = Path.GetExtension(path).ToLower();

        var expander = factory.GetExpander(extension);

        foreach (var expansion in expander.Read(path))
        {
            //Let's go! 
        }
    }
}
```

There is definitely room for improvement, but I hope you get the jist.

If there are any other details that differ between the expanders, you can create another abstract method in the BaseExpander class and have the specialized expanders do whatever needs to be done. You can call the new abstract method from the abstract BaseExpander class since you require anyone that inherits that class implements that method as well. You can always use the reader in its full potential from the specialized class since it is part of the class's type argument.

Let's pretend that JT used base16 for its file encoding and that IGES used base8. We would then change the BaseExpander class to look like this:

```
public abstract class BaseExpander<T> : IExpander where T : Base_Reader
{
    public abstract string Identifier { get; }
    public abstract T CreateReader();
    public abstract void ReadFile(T reader, string path);

    public IEnumerable<WaitUntil> Read(string filePath)
    {
        var reader = CreateReader();
        var aReaderParamaters = reader.Parameters();

        aReaderParamaters.SetDelayedConversion(Settings.DelayedConversion);

        //Here, it used to be reader.ReadFile(new Base_UTF16String(filePath));
        ReadFile(reader, filePath);

        //convert STEP to MDM
        ModelData_Model aLoadedModel = new ModelData_Model();
        var s = reader.Transfer(aLoadedModel);
        //convert MDM to GameObject
        Unity_ObjectFactory aConventer = new Unity_ObjectFactory();
        string aModelName = filePath.Split('/')[filePath.Split('/').Length - 1];
        _meshParentGameObject = aConventer.Create(aLoadedModel, aModelName);

        yield return new WaitUntil(() => _meshParentGameObject != null);
    }


    /* not sure what these are only added them here to compile*/
    private object _meshParentGameObject;
    public IConfiguration Settings { get; private set; }
}
```

And now, the specialized classes look like this:

```
public class JTExpander : BaseExpander<JT_Reader>
{
    public override string Identifier => "jt";
    public IModelReaderFactory ModelReaderFactory { get; }


    public JTExpander(IModelReaderFactory ModelReaderFactory)
    {
        this.ModelReaderFactory = ModelReaderFactory;
    }

    public override JT_Reader CreateReader()
        => ModelReaderFactory.CreateReader<JT_Reader>();

    public override void ReadFile(JT_Reader reader, string path)
    {
        reader.ReadFile(new Base_UTF16String(path));
    }
}

public class IGESExpander : BaseExpander<IGES_Reader>
{
    public override string Identifier => "iges";
    public IModelReaderFactory ModelReaderFactory { get; }


    public IGESExpander(IModelReaderFactory ModelReaderFactory)
    {
        this.ModelReaderFactory = ModelReaderFactory;
    }

    public override IGES_Reader CreateReader()
        => ModelReaderFactory.CreateReader<IGES_Reader>();

    public override void ReadFile(IGES_Reader reader, string path)
    {
        reader.ReadFile(new Base_UTF8String(path));
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your detailed answer but, unfortunatelly I can not use        
 var aReaderParamaters = reader.Parameters();  at base class, because base dont have it. I solved this situation with dynamic type, where compiler doesn't give error at compile time and I get exact reader and use it at runtime.

Comment: This seems like an even better fit for the template pattern: the base class does not have that method. Which means there is no guarantee that it will actually have that method. So create an abstract method that provides the parameters, and force any child classes to implement that. That way, you don't run into any runtime errors.

Comment: Actually there was a base class for readers as Base_ReaderParameters so,
I added an another generic type to BaseModelExpander public abstract class BaseModelExpander<T,T2> : IModelExpander where T : Base_Reader where  T2 : Base_ReaderParameters
and readerParameters become generic too.
After these it works ! 
Thank you so much for your detailed answer and clean architecture. Although I know that your solution is the correct one. 
If I implement your solution I must create more than 20 expander, for the moment I would go for dynamic but near feature I gonna implement this.

Answer (score -2):

Thank you for your answers again. I solved it with dynamic types. Where I changed reader and readerParameters variables as dynamic.

```
    if (brepFormats.Contains(aModelExpansion))
    {
        dynamic aReader = ModelReaderFactory.CreateModelReader(aModelExpansion);
        if (aReader == null)
        {
            Debug.LogError("Haha you get runtime error if you use dynamic...");
            yield break;
        }
        
        dynamic aReaderParamaters = aReader.Parameters();
        
        aReaderParamaters.SetDelayedConversion(Settings.DelayedConversion);
        aReader.ReadFile(new Base_UTF16String(filePath));
        //convert STEP to MDM
        ModelData_Model aLoadedModel = new ModelData_Model();
        var s = aReader.Transfer(aLoadedModel);
        //convert MDM to GameObject
        Unity_ObjectFactory aConventer = new Unity_ObjectFactory();
        string aModelName = filePath.Split('/')[filePath.Split('/').Length - 1];
        _meshParentGameObject = aConventer.Create(aLoadedModel, aModelName);
        
        yield return new WaitUntil(() => _meshParentGameObject != null);
    }

public class ModelReaderFactory
{
    public static dynamic CreateModelReader(string aModelExpansion)
    {
        dynamic aReader = null;
        if (aModelExpansion == ".jt")
            aReader = CreateReader<JT_Reader>();
        if(aModelExpansion == ".step")
            aReader = CreateReader<STEP_Reader>();
        if(aModelExpansion == ".rhino")
            aReader = CreateReader<Rhino_Reader>();
        if(aModelExpansion == ".dwg")
            aReader = CreateReader<DWG_Reader>();
        if(aModelExpansion == ".nx")
            aReader = CreateReader<NX_Reader>();
        if(aModelExpansion == ".solidworks")
            aReader = CreateReader<SLD_Reader>();
        if (aModelExpansion == ".iges")
            aReader = CreateReader<IGES_Reader>();
        if (aModelExpansion == ".ifc")
            aReader = CreateReader<IFC_Reader>();
        if (aModelExpansion == ".acis")
            aReader = CreateReader<ACIS_Reader>();
        if (aModelExpansion == ".parasolid")
            aReader = CreateReader<Para_Reader>();
        if (aModelExpansion == ".catia")
            aReader = CreateReader<CAT_Reader>();
        if (aModelExpansion == ".creo")
            aReader = CreateReader<Creo_Reader>();
        return aReader;
    }

    private static T CreateReader<T>() where T : Base_Reader, new()
    {
        return new T();
    }

}
```